# Having Trouble Making a Button in Xamarin.Mac/XCode-Storyboard

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, iboutlet, xamarin.mac

Let me start off by saying I am new to XCode, but already very experienced in C#. I am having trouble getting the outlet for this button, and every time I try to Control drag it under ViewControl it only lets me do action! I have been googling for about 3 hours and trying to find tutorials, but everyone else's code looks different by default :(

[image: Failed XCode Outlet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to drag into the `ViewController.m` file, you need to be in the header file (`ViewController.h`) to create an `Outlet`.

#### Change the file being edited:

[image]

#### Now Ctrl-Drag into the `.h` file:

[image]

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST! Sorry for such a silly mistake! I added an outlet to change stuff like the title, and I added a action for the click event, but how would I have a event for both click and say onhover? Is that possible, or are events a little harder here than in Visual Studio?

Comment: @SeanMitchell Xcode's UI takes a while to get the hang of... ;-) For `MouseEntered`, `MouseExited`, ..., just subclass `NSButton` and provide the method overrides, for "click" I normally just use the Xamarin/C# normalization of the `Activated` EventHandler (`button.Activated += SomeDelegate;`)